# Each Ansible task in playbook takes 10s to even start

Tags: ansible, winrm

I run the script from AnsibleTower and use WinRM to execute it on a Windows machine.
This script just creates a directory. It takes 8-10s to run it.

In some completely different environments, it takes < 1s.

**What could be wrong in the environment where it takes 8-10s to run each of these tasks?**

```
- hosts: the_test_host
  tasks:
  - name: Create 1st file
    win_file:
      path: D:\test_1.txt
      state: touch

  - name: Create 2nd file
    win_file:
      path: D:\test_2.txt
      state: touch

  - name: Create 3rd file
    win_file:
      path: D:\test_3.txt
      state: touch

  - name: Create 4th file
    win_file:
      path: D:\test_4.txt
      state: touch

  - name: Create 5th file
    win_file:
      path: D:\test_5.txt
      state: touch
```

Comment: Running with `-vvvv` might give you a clue on what hangs on each task. If you are using host names on your inventory, try to use IPs instead as a test on the slow environment. If this is really faster, check your DNS resolution on both ends.

Comment: We are using IPs. But I'll try -vvvv flag.

Answer (score 1):

The main source of playbook start slowdown is fact gathering. Turn it off:

```
- hosts: the_test_host
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    ...
```

The other issues may be with network (latency), gss pam module (for centos; disable it if you can).

If you are desperate for speed, you can try to use connection multiplexing and mitogen, but both would require a decent amount of attention and will yield few unpleasant surprises.

Comment: We even tried by installing WSL (linux subsystem) on target Widnows machine and running ansible playbook from that (locally). It took 6-8s per task of "nothingness" before task started.

Comment: As I said, start from `gather_facts: false`.